# $R$ is a fractional ideal itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In Algebraic number theory by cassels

Proving $I^{-1}=\{\ a\in K\ |\ aI\subset R\}$

and $R(I)=\{\ a\in K\ |\ aI\subset I\}$

are fractional ideals of $R$

using $J=\{\ a\in K\ |\ aI_{2}\subset I_{1}\}$ ($I_1$ and $I_2$ are fractional ideals) is a fractional ideal.

It means $R$ is a fractional ideal of $R$ itself.

Am I right?

Comment: indeed, any ideal of $R$ is also a fractional ideal of $R$. proving this will depend on the definition you've been given of a fractional ideal; try showing it yourself!

Comment: @Atticus Stonestrom thanks, actually I did it a few minutes ago. Now I have a question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product of fractional ideals is a fractional ideal, and given any fractional ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ there exists a fractional ideal $J$ such that $IJ = R$, so yes, $R$ is a fractional ideal of itself.

Comment: thanks I have one more question. In book, $c$ is chosen s.t. $cI_1 \in R$ and $d$ is in $I_2$. Then $cdJ$ is a subset of $R$. but I think $cd$ must be element of $R$. why $d$ is not chosen in $I_2 \cap R$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the Cassels book is already working in the context of Dedekind domains when they introduce fractional ideals, but, just in case it's not, it's perhaps worth clarifying that invertibility of all fractional ideals does not hold in arbitrary integral domains, only in Dedekind domains :)